# populate a sql query into datagridview on vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I wanna populate sql query on datagridview on vb.net
I tried this code that  I found on internet
but I get an error

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        DataGridView2.Visible = False

        Dim Dataconnection As SqlConnection
        Dataconnection.ConnectionString = "server=DESKTOP-514KV5J\SQLEXPRESS;database=A;trusted_connection=True"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        cmd.Connection = Dataconnection
        cmd.CommandText = "select SA,Product,sum(quantity) quantity from(select SA,Product,quantity from tbpurchase union all select SA,Product,-quantity from tbsold)dt group by SA,Product"
        Dim rdr As SqlDataAdapter = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(rdr)
        rdr.close()

        DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

I just want to view the query on datagridview2 whitout any storage on any table .
if you have a solution how can I do it .
because i have 2 tables .
1 for purchasing .
1 for selling.
and the query that i did work on ms sql well and caculates the stock still available
thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the error . This will help us to help you!

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65718143/invalid-column-name-sa) - which contains the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious issues there and, for all we know, there could be more. Firstly, you never actually create a connection object. All you do is declare a variable and then try to set the `ConnectionString` of an object that you never created. That's absolute programming fundamentals and nothing specific to do with data access, so that's not something we should have to explain, especially since you are creating objects later in the code so obviously know how.

Secondly, you aren't even trying to open the connection that you didn't create. If you call `Fill` on a data adapter then it will open and close the connection automatically but, if you use a data reader, you have to do it yourself.

With those two issues in mind and cleaning up the code somewhat, we arrive at this:

```vb
Using connection As New SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-514KV5J\SQLEXPRESS;database=A;trusted_connection=True"),
      command As New SqlCommand("SELECT SA, Product, SUM(Quantity) Quantity FROM (SELECT SA, Product, Quantity FROM tbpurchase UNION ALL SELECT SA, Product, -Quantity FROM tbsold) dt GROUP BY SA, Product", connection)
    connection.Open()

    Dim table As New DataTable

    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        table.Load(reader)
    End Using

    DataGridView2.DataSource = table
End Using
```

For objects that support it, you should always create them with a `Using` block if you are only going to use them then and there, because they will be implicitly disposed at the `End Using` line. It is also preferable to pass arguments to constructors rather than call parameterless constructors and then set properties immediately after.

Comment: when I use this code : I get the following error : Invalid column name 'SA'

Comment: Your the one who put that column name in there, not me. I told you what was wrong with your VB code. You need to use valid column names in your SQL and your database, obviously. Do you have a column named SA? It may be a reserved word, given that it's the name of the inbuilt system administrator user. If that's the case then you need to test it like any other reserved word in the SQL.

Comment: I see that you have posted that as a separate question, in which case this question has been answered, and you should accept the answer.

Comment: thanks the code worked after editing the database

Comment: If this answer has addressed your issue then please accept it so that everyone can see that you no longer need help without having to open the question and read everything. This is an example of why you are supposed to take the site tour before posting; so that you know how the site works.